# Getting runtime exception at MediaRecorder.start()

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am making an app which uses video recording functionality. I have used the code for video recording as suggested on developers website but my app is throwing runtime exception at `MediaRecorder.start()`.
Please can anyone figure out what is the fault in my code?

Here is my java file for it :-

```
public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;
    MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getActionBar().hide();

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        // surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
        Button recBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        recBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // releaseCamera();
                // camera = getCameraInstance();
                try {
                    releaseCamera();
                    startRecording();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(CustomCameraActivity.this,
                        CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.i("Cam open", "" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }

    private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId,
            android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    protected void startRecording() throws IOException {

        camera = getCameraInstance();
        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); // Works well
        // camera.unlock();
        mrec.setCamera(camera);

        // mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        mrec.setOutputFile("/sdcard/zSe.3gp");
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        // camera.release();
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", 0).show();
    }

    protected void stopRecording() {
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        camera.release();
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mrec != null) {
            mrec.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
            mrec = null;
            // camera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a
            // Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        Log.e("camera object", "" + c);
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        camera.stopPreview();
        releaseCamera();
    }

}
```

Logcat :-

```
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity.startRecording(CustomCameraActivity.java:164)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.coderzheaven.pack.CustomCameraActivity$1.onClick(CustomCameraActivity.java:66)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-03 10:11:54.891: E/AndroidRuntime(1199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unlock the camera if you want to use it with MediaRecorder.
So try this:

camera.unlock();

before setting the camera to the MediaRecorder i.e

mrec.setCamera(camera);